# Почему вычисляемое значение не отображается в textBox?

Tags: c#

**C#**. Почему вычисляемое значение не отображается в **textBox**?
**textBox** с серым фоном - вычисляемые значения;
**textBox** с белым фоном - вводимые значения;

```
 for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) // КОЛИЧЕСТВО ЦИКЛОВ ПАРСИНГА{
int plan = Convert.ToInt32(textBox17.Text); // *плановая* длительность 
int fkt = Convert.ToInt32(textBox18.Text); // *фактическая* длительность 
int ost;  // *оставшаяся* длительность
ost = plan - fkt;
textBox15.Text = Convert.ToString(ost);                    
         if (fkt < plan)
         {
          // произвольный код
         }
```

}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если убрать «произвольный код» временно?

Answer (score 1):

1. Не называйте так контролы. Давайте им осмысленные имена: `tbSensitivityDev`, например. Так меньше шансов, что сами запутаетесь в именах
2. Проверьте значение после выхода из цикла.
3. Используйте лучше `int.Parse()` / `int.TryParse()`, а не `Convert`
4. У объектов класса `int` есть метод `toString()`. Не нужно использовать `Convert.ToString()`

P.S. С помощью комбинации клавиш `ctrl+shift+f` ищите все строки `textBox15.Text`, смотрите, где изменяется значение поля, и ставите точку остановки. Потом смотрите, кто зануляет её после присвоения значения.

Comment: ** ОТВЕТ НА 2. Проверьте значение после выхода из цикла ** - проверил. В textBox значения появляются после второго этапа цикла. Причем значения из предыдущего этапа. 
** ОТВЕТ НА PS. смотрите, где изменяется значение поля ** - не совсем понял где искать. обнулений вроде нет. 
** ВОПРОС ** - скорректировал код. Правильно ли я понял п.3,4 вашего сообщения. КОД см. ссылку *** prntscr.com/dcpql8 ***

Comment: @koverflow Поняли правильно. Вашего комментария не понял, насчет метода `ToString()`. Прикрепляю ссылку https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6t7dwaa5(v=vs.110).aspx .

Comment: @koverflow искать нужно во всём коде. Чудес не бывает. Если вы где-то записали значение в переменную, а в результате выполнения кода получили пустую строку, значит вы где-то в другом месте его перезаписали. Верней чудеса бывают, но вряд ли в этом случае.